# Moving parts of a string with a Regex in sed

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to replace,

```
input.output.roomMAX[0]        to   input.output.room[0].MAX
input.output.roomMAX[1]        to   input.output.room[1].MAX
input.output.roomMIN[variable] to   input.output.room[variables].MIN
```

I am getting stuck on how to match things and reference them in the replacement. What argument do I give to `sed`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed 's/room\(MAX\|MIN\)\(\[[^]]*\]\)/room\2.\1/' inputfile
```

If you want to change "variable" to "variables" add another instruction:

```
sed 's/room\(MAX\|MIN\)\(\[[^]]*\]\)/room\2.\1/;s/variable/variables/' inputfile
```

Comment: Or: `sed -r 's/room(MIN|MAX)(\[.*\])/room\2.\1/'` with less escaping.

Comment: @slhck: If your version of `sed` supports it (or `-E` for OS X).

Comment: Yeah. At some point I got used to not using BSD `sed` anymore and using `gsed`, on OS X at least.